# Webpack export class issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, npm-package

it is my index.tsx file inner webpack-my-packages

```
import runApp from './main';
import MyDefaultHelper from './helpers/default-helper';
export default runApp;
export { MyDefaultHelper };
```

My code is ;

```
import {  MyDefaultHelper } from 'webpack-my-packages';
console.log(MyDefaultHelper);
```

I am getting this error;

Module '"micro-frontend-packages"' has no exported member 'OmwoAppKeycloak'. Did you mean to use 'import OmwoAppKeycloak from "micro-frontend-packages"' instead?

My webpack.config.js file is;

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.tsx"),
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    extensionAlias: {
      ".js": [".js", ".ts"],
      ".cjs": [".cjs", ".cts"],
      ".mjs": [".mjs", ".mts"],
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|)$/,
        type: "asset/inline",
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   enforce: "pre",
      //   use: ["source-map-loader"],
      // },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
  plugins: [
    // new CopyWebpackPlugin({ patterns: [{ from: "public" }] }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"),
    }),
  ],
  stats: {
    warnings: false,
  },
  // stats: "errors-only",
};
```

I cannot export the helper libraries which is public libraries on my custom package. How can i fix that problem ?

the runApp function is working well but i cannot use MyDefaultHelper variable.